# Getting error from using postgres function "lower" in JPA Named Queries

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Any idea why hibernate is complaining about the typecasting? I am already passing in as a String to the function. I am using @Query syntax with named parameters. Is it okay to have lower function embedded inside the query?

Source Code:

```
@Query("from UserEntity t where lower(t.email) = lower(:email)")
List<UserEntity> findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function lower(bytea) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 899

nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Related Link: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally understood what is happening. I was getting the error because when I called the function `findByEmail`, in some cases email was `null` which is causing the postgres to complain. I just needed to check for `null` before call this function. Thanks @akshar-patel for trying to help.

Comment: Can we check for `null` value within the function? I mean within the function not before calling.

Comment: @MahmoudMubarak of course we can :email is null or <your condition>

Answer (score -7):

I finally understood what is happening. I was getting the error because when I called the function findByEmail, in some cases email was null which is causing the problem

Comment: You just copied the first part from @raym ag's answer

Comment: That is right. I had the same issue but it's really caused by Null